# Shutting Down Workstation Computer With Batch File

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a laptop and a desktop on the same workstation.  On the desktop I have a virtual that shuts down when the host machine shuts down.  Rather than have to remote from the laptop into the desktop to shut the machine down, can I use a batch file to do this?  Do I have to be able to access the machine as that machine's administrator then, or can I use an account on the laptop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shutdown`.

`shutdown /s /m \\COMPUTERNAME`

There is also [`psshutdown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) from Sysinternals, which allows you to specify an admin account and password.

`psshutdown \\COMPUTERNAME -u user USERNAME -p PASSWORD -k`

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of solutions, you can use `shutdown`, `psshutdown` (from Sysinternals), or using `PowerShell` (a sample script here [Remote Shutdown script](http://www.infotechguyz.com/cmd/powershellremoteshutdown.html)

Answer (score 0):

The title you provided is about using a batch file to shut down a computer, but you didn't mention the OS you're using (probably DOS/Windows though because you used the term "batch file") and your main question doesn't indicate if you have a mechanism in place to detect the shutdown operation, so I'm providing an answer to shutting down your computer from a batch file:

In Unix (e.g., NetBSD, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, Linux, etc.):  shutdown -p now

In Windows, there's a free tool called "Wizmo" by an Assembler programmer named Steve Gibson that will do the job for you -- it provides a variety of shutdown options and can be called from a batch file:  http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.html

In DOS, I'm not aware of any such tool.

I hope that helps.

Comment: He mentioned the OS in the tags.